# ActiveX TextBox_Change with ListBox_Click then clear TextBox causes recursive behavior

Tags: excel, activex, vba

I have an ActiveX TextBox with TextBox_Click code behind it such that each character I type triggers another sub to execute which then updates a table by updating a named cell that as a formula in it which drives the table. Then I have a ListBox that has ListFillRange linked to that table. The result is each character I type in the TextBox causes the ListBox to update. This is working fine.

The next thing I put in place was ListBox_Click code so that when I click on an item in the ListBox it updates a Label.Caption then sets ListBox.Value="". This is also working fine.

What I would like to now is have the TextBox clear after the Label.Caption is assigned. The problem is the TextBox clear causes the ListBox to update and the Label then gets the wrong value. This seems odd because the command assign the caption occurs before setting the TextBox = "" which resets the ListBox. But it doesnt seem to matter that the caption assignment occurrs first. The ListBox seems still selected so the update of the TextBox updates the ListBox so the Label gets the wrong value.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

This is in the Sheet's module

```
Private Sub TextBox5_Change()

    Call UpdateValues(TextBox5.Value)

End Sub
```

This is in a general module

```
Sub UpdateValues(SearchString As String)
    Range("mySearchString").Value = SearchString
    Range("myStartPosition").Value = Range("myOverwriteProtection").Value
End Sub
```

This is in the Sheet's module

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Label33").Object.Caption = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object.Value

    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object.Value = ""

    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox5").Object.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options really.

1. Don't use ListFillRange. Unless you need column headers, there is no need to use this property - you're already using code, so you can repopulate the list in code using code like:

   `control_name.List = Sheets("Sheet name").Range("some range").Value`
2. Use a Boolean flag to stop the event. As the first line of each event, use:

   `If flag_variable then exit sub`

Then whenever you need to do something and don't want to run control events, simply set the variable to True, perform your actions and then set it back to False. (it's a bit like using `Application.EnableEvents`, which doesn't work for ActiveX control events)

Comment: Thanks Rory.  For 1. are you saying that instead of using LIstFillRange to populate a sheet directly?  Also, I'm not sure how to implement 2.  The Application.EnableEvents=False didn't work for a Click event.  Would I exit the Click Sub by setting that flag you suggest and then test if the flag is true and if so execute another Sub that copies over the values and clears the TextBox?

Comment: Re 1, see my edit about using the List property. Re 2, each event code needs to check that flag variable and just exit if it's true. You can then prevent events from firing by just setting the variable to True, doing whatever you need to do, then set it back to False.

Comment: I think I understand 2, thanks.  For 1, could you be a more specific please (I'm a rookie) or point me at a reference? I'm trying to create a prototype that I can provide to a developer to more clearly show what I'm thinking.  My intention for this part is to have a list update as the user types into a box (like for looking up a name) and when the user sees the name appear in the list they can click on it which triggers other things occuring (retrieve address, etc).  It looks like I can't use ListBox2.List=Sheets("name").Range("rng").Value. Is there some other control you have in mind?

Comment: I was following this concept:  http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2010/09/scroll-and-search-in-excel-dashboard-tables.html  but I'm not wedded to it.  I'm happy to use any tools to achieve this functionality.  Ultimately this will get coded in Java or PHP or something like that for a webpage (if I get this idea off the ground).

Comment: Why can't you use the `.List` property?

Comment: I just added ListBox2 and created a test sub with one line of code: ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox2").List = Sheets("Search Criteria Control").Range("F2:F21") but it gives error "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: You missed a bit: `ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox2").Object.List = Sheets("Search Criteria Control").Range("F2:F21").Value` or just `ActiveSheet.ListBox2.List = Sheets("Search Criteria Control").Range("F2:F21").Value`

Comment: Thank you. Interesting that List is not a property that comes up in the Properties box.  I substituted this into the sub i'm working on: ActiveSheet.ListBox1.List = Sheets("Search Criteria Control").Range("F2:F21").Value and get error 'Permission denied'.  Is there something obvious?

Comment: You'll need to clear the `ListFillRange` property from the control first. The reason that the List property doesn't appear in Intellisense is simply that the compiler is seeing a generic Object type, not the specific control type.

Comment: ActiveSheet.ListBox1.Clear gives an unspecified error.  You've been very helpful. I'll put this as a new question so you can disentangle yourself from this.